# How can I subdivide a plane with a complex contour?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, bezier-curves, faces, subdivision-surface

I'm probably asking a very strange question, but...
I've drawn a random outline with Bezier curves and meshed it to create a plane object. How can I subdivide this into smaller pieces? Is there a way to subdivide it into a grid, like you would subdivide a simple square plane? (Like the pink line in the reference image).

[image]

[image]


**Update 1** (It's solved!)

- I followed Moonboots's advice.
  [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing you can simplify your topology with a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* and tweak the angle parameter in the *Operator* box. As for your question, you can use the *Knife Project* tool. The process has changed a bit since the latest versions:

Create a grid (subdivided plane), delete the faces to keep the edges only (<kbd>X</kbd> *> Only Faces*), put it above your object:

[image]

Select your plane, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click on the grid, choose the top view, go into the *Mesh* panel > *Knife Project*:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Comment: I did exactly what you told me to do. It worked like a magic! Thank you very much! those pictures made it so much easier to understand.